# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined Next JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Main.js

```js
import {
  Navbar,
  Footer,
  Landing,
  About,
  Skills,
  Testimonials,
  Blog,
  Contacts,
  Projects,
  Services,
  Portfolio,
} from "../../components";

function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Landing />
      <About />
      <Skills />
      <Projects />
      <Portfolio />
      <Services />
      <Testimonials />
      <Blog />
      <Contacts />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

index.js

```js
import { Head } from "next/Head";
import { Main } from './Main/Main';
import { headerData } from "../data/headerData";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{headerData.name}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="./channels4_profile.jpg" />
      </Head>

      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Please Please The Solution

Comment: try `import Main from ....`

Answer (score 1):

Like [cmgchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess) alluded to in the comments, since you are using `export default Main;` you don't import it as a named function.

Change this:
`import { Main } from './Main/Main';`
to this:
`import Main from './Main/Main';`

If that doesn't work, see if you can get a simpler version of Main to import at all. Try something like:

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      Main imported
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you can get that working, add back the other components one by one until you find which one is causing the issue.